# My core-transition example does not work?

Tags: polymer

After reading http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-transition I am trying the following but I am doing something wrong or did not understand it. When I click on my red test square nothing happens except for my console log message?

```
<link href="components/core-transition/core-transition-css.html" rel="import">

<polymer-element name="story-1">

    <template>

        <style>
            :host {
                position:absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
            }

            #container {
                position: absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }

            .card {
                position: relative;
                height: 150px;
                width: 150px;
                font-size: 50px;
                margin: 8px;
                background-color: tomato;
                border-radius: 4px;
                cursor: default;
            }
        </style>

        <div id="container" flex horizontal wrap around-justified layout>

            <div class="card" id="animate-me" vertical center center-justified layout on-tap="{{ani}}">
                  test
            </div>

        </div>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('story-1', {

            ani: function() {
                console.log('???')
                var target = document.getElementById('animate-me');

                var meta = document.createElement('core-meta');
                meta.type = 'transition';

                transition = meta.byId('core-transition-fade');
                transition.go(target, true);
            }

        });
    </script>

</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the part I got wrong

```
<script>
    Polymer('story-1', {

        ani: function() {
            var target = this.$.animate_me;

            var meta = document.createElement('core-meta');
            meta.type = 'transition';

            transition = meta.byId('core-transition-fade');
            transition.setup(target);
            transition.go(target, true);
        }

    });
</script>
```

As far as I can tell from the documentation `transition.setup(target, true);` is not mentioned in the example. I had to figure that out from the demo source code.

(see https://github.com/Polymer/core-transition/issues/4)